# Linux startx qt border

Tags: linux, qt, xorg

I am run my programm with next command, `startx -e qtapp` . But all dialog windows shows without border. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run a WindowManager to allow your application to be managed using windows. A lightweight one to try is OpenBox.

Rather than start your application as a parameter to startx, instead use .xinitrc to start your application. You must start your windowmanager last - it then controls when to exit X.

Comment: Here is a guide on getting started with openbox. You will be interested in the "The lightweight approach" http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Getting_started

Answer (score 0):

You can either go the route of bazwilliams or you can draw your own border/window controls. Which will work fine but it'll be a pain to do consistently.